# n-sphere coordinate system to Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any efficient way of changing between Cartesian coordinate system and [n-spherical one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)? The transformation is as follows:
[image]

The following is my code but I want to get rid of the loop:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

    def coord_transform_n(r,alpha):
        """alpha: the n-2 values between [0,\pi) and last one between [0,2\pi)
        """
        x=[]
        for i in range(alpha.shape[0]):
            x.append(r*np.prod(np.sin(alpha[0:i]))*np.cos(alpha[i]))
        return np.asarray(x)
    print coord_transform_n(1,np.asarray(np.asarray([1,2])))
```

Comment: I realised my code is not correct. I am not including the last coordinate, namely x_n!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original code can be sped up by memoizing intermediate `sin` product, i.e.

```
def ct_dynamic(r, alpha):
    """alpha: the n-2 values between [0,\pi) and last one between [0,2\pi)
    """
    x = np.zeros(len(alpha) + 1)
    s = 1
    for e, a in enumerate(alpha):
        x[e] = s*np.cos(a)
        s *= np.sin(a)
    x[len(alpha)] = s
    return x*r
```

But still loses in speed to numpy based approach

```
def ct(r, arr):
    a = np.concatenate((np.array([2*np.pi]), arr))
    si = np.sin(a)
    si[0] = 1
    si = np.cumprod(si)
    co = np.cos(a)
    co = np.roll(co, -1)
    return si*co*r

>>> n = 10
>>> c = np.random.random_sample(n)*np.pi
>>> all(ct(1,c) == ct_dynamic(1,c))
True

>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import coord_transform_n as f, c; f(2.4,c)', number=10000)
2.213547945022583

>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import ct_dynamic as f, c; f(2.4,c)', number=10000)
0.9227950572967529

>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import ct as f, c; f(2.4,c)', number=10000)
0.5197498798370361
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realised my code is not correct. I am not including the last coordinate, namely x_n!

Comment: @Naji it's not hard to fix it, all the evaluations already done. I updated my answer to correct implementations, leave yours to you ;)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion: Assemble the sinus in one vector, use cumprod on it, then multiply each one with the cosinus (preassembled in another vector).