# Hyper-spherical Coordinates Implementation

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, coordinates

Does anyone know of a well-tested, reliable implementation of hyper-spherical coordinates, converting Cartesian vectors to spherical angles? I'd prefer python but I can translate it if necessary.

In other words, essentially the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133318/n-sphere-coordinate-system-to-cartesian-coordinate-system).

Before you tell me it's trivial to implement, here is my implementation (for 5 dimensional space):

```
def theta(x):
   n = 5
   x = np.array(x)
   toFill = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
   r_array = np.sqrt( np.array( [ sum( [xj**2 for xj in x[i+1:]] ) for i in range(0,n-1) ] ) )
   for k in range(0,n-2): 
      toFill[k] = np.arctan2( r_array[k] , x[k] ) 
   toFill[n-2] = 2 * np.arctan2( x[n-1] , ( x[n-2] + np.sqrt(x[n-1]**2 + x[n-2]**2) ) ) 
   return toFill
```

Note that I only care about the angles, not the radius. The implementation is essentially from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

It seems to work, but I'm getting some odd results in some simulations (which I think may be due to this method, though I haven't found the problem directly yet). If you can see some boundary condition issues here, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by odd results? I shortly tested it with the function given in the other post you mention, but couldn't find anything weird, the result was always "perfect".

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Thank you for checking. It looks like the problem is elsewhere! I have posted [a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401833/how-can-i-additively-perturb-angular-orientations) if you'd like to look at it. Unless others dislike it, I'll leave this one open in case someone does know of a battle-tested library with a hyper-spherical coordinates implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to implement in Numpy, just a bit frustrating.

Here is some working code which gives identical results as yours. I tested it also using the inverse Cartesian transform. The code will be efficient only for many and high-dimensional vectors, though.

```py
def angular_coordinates(x):
    """
    Calculate angular coordinates of the vectors in `x` along the first axis.

    Source:
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates
    """
    a = x[1:] ** 2
    b = np.sqrt(np.cumsum(a[::-1], axis=0))
    phi = np.arctan2(b[::-1], x[:-1])
    phi[-1] *= np.sign(x[-1])
    return phi
```